# Can't change the selection after cloning a select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select field

```
<div class="col-xs-10 selectContainer" id="jc_leader_input_field" style="display: inline;">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" style="margin:0px;padding:0px" value="" data-size="15">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">Option1</option>
        <option value="1">Option0</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now I want to clone this object and include it in my form

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var selectfield = $('#jc_leader_input_field').clone();
selectfield.attr('id','test');
selectfield.appendTo(div); 
$('#group_leaders_inputs').append(div);
```

where `#group_leaders_inputs` refers to the form. The cloning and insertion works fine, but I can't change any of the options in the copied select field.

I made a fiddle to illustrate the problem... while making it I noticed that without bootstrap-select it actually works fine
http://jsbin.com/vonoqazawa/edit?html,output

Comment: Mind giving an example snippet/fiddle of this? More specifically the `#group_leaders_inputs` element. The code you provided doesn't have enough information to be a functional example.

Comment: When you say "I can't change the options", do you mean that you can't select any of them in the second `select`, or that you can't modify what choices show up?

Comment: Put your complete code. Where do you change the selection? as I see, you are cloning the div. not the select

Comment: yes I can't change the selection in the selectfield... I will prepare a fiddle

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsbin.com/vonoqazawa/edit?html,output... I noticed that when excluding bootstrap-select it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the Bootstrap selectpicker. To make it work, you can:

1. Remove the selectpicker from the original select control
2. Clone the original element and add it to the DOM
3. Reactivate the selectpicker for both select controls

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-add").click(function (evt) {
        var $originalDiv = $('#jc_leader_input_field');
        var $originalSelect = $originalDiv.find('.selectpicker');
        $originalSelect.selectpicker('destroy').addClass('tmpSelect');
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = 'col-xs-12';
        div.style = 'margin:0px;padding:0px';
        var selectfield = $originalDiv.clone();
        selectfield.attr('id', 'test');
        selectfield.appendTo(div);
        $('#group_leaders_inputs').append(div);
        $('.tmpSelect').selectpicker().removeClass('tmpSelect');
    });
});
```

I saved a modified version of your fiddle [here](http://jsbin.com/facabarifi/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: I had some trouble to implement it, but this solution works fine if you use bootstrap-select 1.11.2... when using older versions it does not quite work...